# Irreducible quotient of $U\otimes V$

Tags: rt.representation-theory, lie-algebras

All modules here are finite dimensional. The field is over complex number. Let $U$ be an irreducible $\mathfrak{sl}_n$-module, and $V$ is a highest weight $\mathfrak{sl}_n$-module. Suppose $U\otimes V$ is not a highest weight representation. Then $U\otimes V$ has an irreducible quotient $W$. My question is: what is the maximal vector of $W$? or if $u^{-}\otimes v^{+}$ can be a maximal vector of $W$? It is known that $u^{-}\otimes v^{+}$ generates $U\otimes V$.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why will that tensor product have a unique irreducible quotient?

Comment: The formulation is a bit loose and symbols undefined, as comments indicate.   In any case, you should specify what kind of field you are working over and whether any of the modules is assumed to be finite dimensional.  (And some motivation for the question might help.)

Comment: P.S. Given the new formulation, complete reducibility makes it easy to control the highest weight occurring in such a tensor product.   So there seems to be no real problem here.

Comment: Given the new formulation, I would say this is not a research level question. The tensor product is a direct sum of simple modules, and the highest weights of those are given by the Littlewood-Richardson rule. Also, the formulation is a bit strange, as a finite dimensional highest weight module is the same as a finite dimensional simple module.

Answer (score 1):

Your notation suggests that that $u^-$ is a lowest weight vector, so I will asssume that this is the case. Then $u^-\otimes v^+$ generates $U\otimes V$. Indeed, let $W$ be the $\mathfrak{sl}_n$-submodule of $U\otimes V$ generated by $u^-\otimes v^+$ and write $\mathfrak{b}_+$ and $\mathfrak{b}_ -$ for the positive and the negative Borel subalgebras of $\mathfrak{sl}_n$. As $U$ is generated by $u^-$ over $U(\mathfrak{b}_+)$, we have that $W$ contains $u\otimes v^+$ for all $u\in U$. If $x\in \mathfrak{b}_-$ then $x(u\otimes v^+)=x(u)\otimes v^++u\otimes x(v^+)$, which implies that $u\otimes x(v_+)\in W$ for all $u\in U$ and $x\in\mathfrak{b}_-$. Since $V=U(\mathfrak{b}_{-})v_+$ we obtain $W=U\otimes V$ as wanted.

Comment: But he wrote that he knew that this was the case. The question was about the highest weight of an irreducible quotient of the tensor product (I am still not sure why there should be a unique such).

Comment: $W$ is irreducible, the maximal vector is unique up to scalar.

Comment: @YilanTan Yes, but why will the irreducible quotient be unique?

Comment: any cyclic module will have a unique irreducible quotient: take the maximal submodule not containing the cyclic vector (Zorn's lemma) and go modulo that maximal one.

Comment: @Aakumadula: But why should the maximal submodule be unique?

Comment: This argument confuses me. Take $U$, $V$ to be finite-dimensional and simple. Then $W = U \otimes V$ satisfies the desired conditions but in general it will certainly not be irreducible, and it will not have a unique maximal vector - it will have lots of them.

Comment: Thank you all to answer my quetstion. If you are of interest, I tell you why I ask this question. I am doing a research on Weyl module of Yangian of sl_n. The irreducible module of sl_n with fundamental weight is an fundamental representation of Yangian of sl_n, which is called evaluation representation. V.Chari proved, in paper Yangian-their representation and character, that $\bigotimes W_{1}(a_i)$ is a highest weight representation if $a_i-a_j\neq 1$ for $i<j$. Here, $W_{1}(a_i)$ is the irreducible module $V(1)$ of sl_2 pulled back by a automorphism $\tau_a$ of yangian of sl_2.

Comment: In the prove of it, Chari showed that there is an automorphism $F: V\rightarrow U^t\otimes W$, where $V=\otimes_{i=2} W_{a_i}$ is a highest weight module, $U^t$ is a fundamental representation, and $W$ is an irreducible quotient of $\otimes_{i=1}W_1(a_i)$. Chari claimed that $F(v^+)$ must be a scalar of $u^+\otimes w^+$ without details. It cost me very very long time to figure this out. But my way is too complicated, and I thought it may not be the way Chari thought. Thank you all again for your help.